# Methane vs propane as rocket fuel

Tags: rockets, propulsion, fuel

How would propane compare with methane as rocket fuel?

Propane can also be stored as liquid under pressure.

Comment: [very related](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/38181/why-did-orbex-choose-propane-as-its-fuel?rq=1)